# How to construct a Platform::Array from a std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++-cx

I thought it works like this

```
std::vector<char> array;
Platform::Array<char>^ data = ref new Platform::Array<char>(array, array.size());
```

but says "no instance of constructor matches the argument list"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send pointer to constructor of [Platform::Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/hh441578.aspx) and `std::vector` is class, not array.

```
Platform::Array<char>^ data = ref new Platform::Array<char>(array.data(), 
array.size());
```

If C++11 is enabled, or

```
Platform::Array<char>^ data = ref new Platform::Array<char>(&array[0], 
array.size());
```

if not (it is UB to access first element in empty vector, so I have no idea about how we can get access to underlying array before C++11, when vector is empty).

Comment: Constructing a pointer to the first element past the end of the controlled sequence is legal in C++. Dereferencing that pointer would yield UB, but I would assume that the `Platform::Array` c'tor knows how to deal with zero-sized input.